# Puzzling Javascript- constructor passing into function issue, only affecting strings

Tags: javascript, constructor, template-literals

I am relatively new to Javascript and coding so please be kind if I am not using the right lingo! I am studying and my teacher is also stumped by this, so thought it would be worth asking here!

I am currently making a basic pizza ordering website.

I have create a class for my menu items (pizzas, drinks, etc) and each object has the same constructors - name, ingredients, price as shown here:

```
class MenuItem{
    constructor(
        name,
        ingredients,
        price
    ){
    this.name = name;
    this.ingredient = ingredients;
    this.price = price
}

//function for the class to add each item to menu
addToMenu(){
    const item = `
    <h2>${this.name}:</h2>
    <p>${this.ingredient}</p>
    <p>$${this.price}</p>
    <button onclick="addToOrder(${this.price}, ${this.name})">Add to order</button>`
    return item;
}
```

I call this addToOrder function when I create the object, and place the menu item within divs I have sitting empty:

```
document.querySelector(".product1").innerHTML = classicVeg.addToMenu();
```

Here is this object being created:

```
const classicVeg = new MenuItem(
    "Classic Vegetarian",
    "Olives, tomatoes, cheese, spinach, basil",
    14.99,
)
```

I have the addToOrder function sitting within a script tag on my HTML page, as when the page first loads it does not exist on the page until they press a button to populate either the pizza options, drinks, sides.

```
let runningTotal = 0;

        function addToOrder(price, name){
        const item = document.createElement("P");
        item.innerText = price + name;
        document.querySelector(".totals").append(item);
        runningTotal += price;
        document.querySelector(".orderTotal").innerText = runningTotal; 
        }
```

I think that is enough background. The issue I am having is that the addToOrder function is supposed to put the price of a pizza and the name of the pizza inside a box I have called totals.

I am getting an error (sending me to line 1 of my HTML page) saying I am missing a ')'.

However, if I change the name of a pizza to a number when I create the object I can get both this.name and this.price to display.

Is there a way for me to explicitly say that a constructor is meant to be a string?

Thanks!

Comment: Please put your code in the question.  External links aren't great as they have a tendency to disappear, making the question lose a lot of value.

Comment: It doesn't work because you're missing quotes around the name.  Try `<button onclick="addToOrder(${this.price}, '${this.name}')">Add to order</button>`.  Output of your version is `onclick="addToOrder(14.99, Classic Vegetarian)"`, which isn't valid JavaScript.  Probably want to consider not using `onclick` at all, but rather adding event handlers.

Comment: Thanks @Tibrogargan. That seems to have fixed it, but not for all objects. Even though all objects are constructed the same way I still get the error "Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument listmenu.html:1:23" on most of my objects. Any idea where that might be coming from?

Comment: Frankly, your app is not architected at all well.  Your `script.js` builds a lot of stuff and then adds them to the page.  This is pretty much the root cause of the issue.  What you should be doing is creating a data model (i.e. model.js) that just contains your stuff and maybe some helper functions.  i.e.  `var pizzas = [ new MenuItem('Classic Vegetarian', 14.99, [ 'olives', 'peppers', 'onions', ... ], new MenuItem('Blah', ... ) ... ]`.  Then including that in some UI building script that iterates over your pizzas array.  Don't really have time to diagnose.  View source is your friend.

Comment: Don't take that comment badly.  You're probably being taught coding techniques before you're being taught architectural concerns - fairly normal curriculum.  I suspect you're doing things that are advanced for your class, but just don't have the framework to apply them correctly.  Take a look at Model View Controller (MVC) patterns,  Will go a long way to help you avoid situations that contribute to bugs like this.

Comment: Appreciate the feedback @Tibrogargan and recommendation for next steps! Very new to this so no offense taken.